# Small caps and old style numerals not working with XeTeX in 2021

Tags: fonts, xetex, small-caps, oldstylenums

As above, I'm having difficulty getting **small caps** and **old style numerals** to print properly when using **[CMU Serif](https://www.cufonfonts.com/font/cmu-serif)** with **XeTeX**.

**I'm aware that this is a topic that has been discussed before** but I wasn't able to solve my problem using those previous answers. Previous solutions seem mostly to concern fixing a bug in a MikTeX update, and I use TeX Live.

Here's a MWE of my problem. You can obtain the same version of CMU Serif as me from the link above.

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}

Hello, 1234567890!\\

\textsc{goodbye!}

\end{document}
```

If I run the above through a `xelatex main.pdf`, the numbers are not old style, and the 'goodbye' is printed in all lower case letters. However, if I change the line `setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{CMU Serif}` to `setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}`, everything works - except that it's not in the font I want! This suggests to me that **the font files for CMU Serif are the problem**. Is that the case?

My current file for "CMU Serif, Roman" contains 700 glyphs. Is that too few? If it is, I'm having trouble tracking down a more complete set of Computer Modern .ttf files.

Comment: cmu is part of the standard tex distributions you shouldn't need to install it by hand. Using the copy in texlive 2021 on your test ffile (minus the spurious `\\ `) I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOxHE.png)

Comment: specifically it is in texlive as `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/cmunrm.otf`

Comment: oh check if it works with lualatex xelatex by default can not find texlive fonts by internal font name, so use `\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{cmunrm.otf}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Your suggestions worked. Feel free to put it into a proper answer.

Comment: That might have some trouble finding the other faces, such as bold and italic.

Comment: Works for me, because I installed the CMU fonts in the system. How to do it depends on your OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading fonts by file name is currently the recommended way, but simply loading `cmunrm.otf` will not find the other font faces, such as bold or italic.  To enable these, you may use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures[CMUSerif]{
  Ligatures={Common,TeX},
  Numbers=OldStyle,
  UprightFont=cmunrm,
  BoldFont=cmunbx,
  ItalicFont=cmunti,
  SlantedFont=cmunsl,
  BoldItalicFont=cmunbi,
  BoldSlantedFont=cmunbl,
  Extension=.otf}

\setmainfont{CMUSerif}

\begin{document}
\noindent Computer Modern Serif \textit{Italic} \textsl{Slanted} \textsc{Small Caps \textsl{Oblique}}
\textbf{Bold \textit{Italic} \textsl{Slanted} \textsc{Small Caps}}
\end{document}
```

You may also save the `\defaultfontfeatures` command to a file named `CMUSerif.fontspec`, which will allow you to use `\setmainfont{CMUSerif}` in your documents.

If you need to do the same for sans-serif or typewriter, the [index of filenames is here.](https://cm-unicode.sourceforge.io/font_table.html)  Another good alternative is to load `\usepackage{newcomputermodern}`.

You will not need to bother with this extra setup, although it will still work, if XeTeX or LuaTeX is already configured to look up the font by its display name.  You can test whether XeTeX has this font in its index with `fc-match "CMU Serif"`, and whether LuaTeX does with `luaotfload-tool --find="CMU Serif"`.

If your Linux system does not find your fonts automatically, locate the configuration file you need with `kpsewhich texlive-fontconfig.conf` and symlink or copy it to `/etc/fonts/conf.d/`, or the appropriate directory on your system.  You might also want to refresh your font caches with `fc-cache -f -s -v` and `luaotfload-tool -f -u -p -v`.  You can also install the fonts as system fonts, to be able to use them in all your applications.  On Linux, XeTeX and LuaTeX should also be able to find them in your user font directories, so you should be able to put a copy or symlink to a font directory of your TeX tree in `~/.fonts/`.